Rocky Linux Install Python Packages for all users
I am trying to install python3.11 and some packages for all users in system using Rocky Linux.
I was able to install python3.11 and its accessible by all users in the system. However when trying to use pip to install packages as root, the packages are installed in

/usr/local/lib64/python3.11/site-packages

WARNING: The script pyjson5 is installed in '/usr/local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script wheel is installed in '/usr/local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script wsdump is installed in '/usr/local/bin' which is not on PATH.

instead of

/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages

I feel that it should be installed in the second location as I see the following when using sys.path() as a normal user.
Python 3.11.7 (main, Jan 22 2024, 00:00:00) [GCC 11.4.1 20231218 (Red Hat 11.4.1-3)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib64/python311.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.11', '/usr/lib64/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages']

I have tried to use --system, --install-options, ----config_settings with pip but non of these have worked.
